# How to sync git repo with VSCode (gui) conneted to remote WSL

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I want to "synchronize changes" between a remote repo on Git with a copy that is located on my local machine's WSL (not WSL2 yet).

This can be easily done in the WSL bash terminal with the "git push" command and an SSH key (located in ~/.ssh of the WSL instance and password protected); but, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this in the GUI.

I am connecting "remotely" to WSL on my local, using the "Remote - WSL" VSCode extension.

At present, clicking on the "synchronize changes" button will open a dialogue that says, "This action will push and pull commits to and from 'origin/master'", and clicking "OK" results in:

```
Git: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Its seems like there needs to be some step(s) that will allow VSCode to use an SSH key (either in WSL or copied to Windows), but after reading [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) and [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting), I'm coming up short on a solution.

Any advice is appreciated; thanks.

Comment: Before I could use Git in VS-Code on my Windows machine I had to install git bash: https://gitforwindows.org. Even though I never use it on it's own, it was still required before I could use the VS-code GUI. Have you downloaded this already?

Comment: Hi; thanks; yeah... I do have git bash installed in Windows.  And that's related to my quandary:  how does VSCode push/pull a local repo in local WSL with a remote repo via git?

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you need to do is set up the SSH key.

Next, check if your existing file has a remote connection over HTTPS, you can check this by `git remote -v` if the remote links start with `https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME.GIT`, consider it's an HTTPS link, that very obvious.

Next, remove the remote connection using `git remote remove origin` and add a new remote. This time consider an SSH route.

For example, if you're deploying to Github, you get the option to add remote link as HTTPS, or SSH. Select the SSH option and Eureka! You're done.
That's it.

CONCLUSION: Initialize your file with an SSH link, not HTTPS.

Comment: This is not the correct answer for given question.

OP has already setup the ssh repo and is able to pull / push using terminal, question is regarding 'Permission Denied' error coming in VSCode GUI.